# Fixing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

> I'm trying to make a slideshow in my react app. I'm using the below function for the slideshow.

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("diabetes-day");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}
```

```html
<div className="slideshow-container">
  <div className="diabetes-news">
    <img className="diabetes-day" src={DiabetesDay}/>
    <img className="diabetes-day" src={Symptoms}/>
    <img className="diabetes-day" src={Managing}/>
  </div>
</div>
```

> When I run the code the slideshow works. But as soon as I refresh the page all the contents in the page disappears and I get the following error in my console.[image: Screenshot of the Error]

> I'm not quite sure why it stops working once the page is refreshed. It would be great if someone could guide me on how to fix this.

Comment: The error is probably caused in `x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";`. Does `x[myIndex - 1]` exist?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your code with line 59?

Comment: @GeekyQuentin No, don't post screenshots of code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc."

Comment: so that I could know what line 59 contents are; or else just comment down the line 59 code

Comment: @GeekyQuentin Line 59 is inside `carousel` function. It's either `x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";` or `x[i].style.display = "none";`

Comment: @jabaawithout that the slides aren't working

Comment: This error message means that `x[myIndex - 1]` is `undefined`.

Comment: @GeekyQuentin line 59 is `x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";

Comment: You are passing carousel() as the callback for setTimeout, while it contains the call to setTimeout itself. That seems hard to understand and unreasonable.

Comment: perhaps you can help with a minimal reproduction example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or put debugger point in dev tools to check why x[i]/x[myIndex - 1] is undefined

Comment: change `className=` with `class=` in HTML code

Comment: @ismailbilal https://www.reactjstutorials.com/react-advanced/17/react-class-name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seems that you are working with reactjs, it's better to change your code with this :

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0);

  // change these images with yours
  const imagesSrc = [
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/03/11/19/nature-7045133_960_720.jpg",
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg",
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/18/20/26/sea-164989_960_720.jpg",
  ];

  const carousel = () => {
    setImageIndex((prev) => (prev < 2 ? prev + 1 : 0));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      carousel();
    }, 2000); // set the which timer you want
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="slideshow-container">
      <div className="diabetes-news">
        <img className="diabetes-day" src={imagesSrc[imageIndex]} alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.diabetes-day{
  width: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Can you describe what you've changed, what caused the problem and how you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the same error on refreshing the page. I have used the useEffect hook to solve this error.

```
useEffect(() => {
  //your code
}, [value that is changing]);
```